# React — анимация смены роута. Появляются два одинаковых компонента одного роута. В чем может быть причина?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Делаю анимацию "слайдер" - компонент текущего роута уезжает влево, компонент нового роута выезжает справа.

При смене роута - компонент текущего роута исчезает и повляются ДВА компонента для нового роута.

Скрин:

[image]

Простой пример в песочнице:
[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/6zmx6x2z1z)

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

`<Route path="/:user/:commit">` - этот роут используется без exact, следовательно у тебя срабатывает одновременно `<Route exact path="/:user" component={UserPage} />` и `<Route path="/:user/:commit">`, поэтому и возникает 2 компонента. Просто напиши `<Route exact path="/:user/:commit">`